# getting innerHTML value from page using jmeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

```
WebElement el = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='grid']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[16]"));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver; 
        String returnText = js.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", el).toString();
```

The above code fetches the value for me using selenium.
How to achieve the same while doing it from jmeter?

Answer (score 2):

JMeter provides [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) Post Processor.

You can try out evaluating your XPath with it and store result into a JMeter variable. You might need to append `/text()` function to the end or parse resulting JMeter variable with a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [Beanshell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675711/how-to-use-bean-shell-sampler-in-jmeter), but if your application is XHTML-compliant and XPath is valid (personally I don't like stuff as `div[2]` or `/td[16]` as any slight layout change will cause XPath selector to fail, JMeter will evaluate your XPath and saves the match into a variable.